# Can I have a custom URL format in Yii

Tags: php, url, yii, url-rewriting

Following is the URL:

```
http://localhost/abc/xyz/ddd.php?json=[{ "rrrr": "ABC", "vvvv": "56464rgdfSAA345", "uuuuu": "12345678"}]
```

The above URL is in core PHP, I want to give the same format in Yii framework for web service. 
How do I give the following part url in Yii:

```
http://localhost/abc/xyz/ddd.php?json=[{ "rrrr": "ABC", "vvvv": "56464rgdfSAA345", "uuuuu": "12345678"}]
```

Can anyone out there let me know what I can do to achieve such an URL in Yii?

Comment: What are the controller and the action here?
You should take a look at URL Management: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: @CMate  sorry for the delay actually  it's core PHP url format where "xyz" is  a folder and  "ddd.php" is the web service file .for yii url format "abc" is project name "xyz" -controller and "ddd.php"-action how to i achieve this -> .... " json=[{ "rrrr": "ABC", "vvvv": "56464rgdfSAA345", "uuuuu": "12345678"}] " ...............  in url

Answer (score 1):

In UrlManager config:

```
'rules' => array(
    'xyz/ddd.php?json=<json>' => 'xyz/customAction',
```

In controller XyzController.php:

```
public action customAction($json) {

    // do something
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay will.... "$json" ... contain this --> [{ "rrrr": "ABC", "vvvv": "56464rgdfSAA345", "uuuuu": "12345678"}] and  in rule.........   "?json=<json>"  i.e., <json> can contain this part odf it ....... [{ "rrrr": "ABC", "vvvv": "56464rgdfSAA345", "uuuuu": "12345678"}]